# Email Sharepoint documents

Tags: document-library, email

Now sharepoint provides the ability to send document link as Email. Is it possible to send sharepoint document as attachments via Email?

Comment: can you provide a little more context of how you are trying to accomplish this?

Comment: I am trying to send sharepoint document to other user through email. Also checking for possibility to receive mail from user to sharepoint.

Comment: Do you mean to send the file via e-mail? That usually breaks the purpose of having a document library and a email link to that document that contain all the revisions and version on one place, and not "copying" the document and make several different versions? Or did you mean a document that can be synced back to Sharepoint?

Comment: yes. we are maintaining documents here. But some documents needs to be reviewed by other users who don't have access to sharepoint site.

Comment: What is the process that will trigger this? If it is something you want to occour automatically you may want to look into creating a workflow or event reciever, if you are looking for this to be an action initiated by a user then Jakobsen's solution below looks viable.

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box but it seems there is a codeplex project which is exactly what you request: [Send Documents as attachments with SharePoint 2010](http://sendemailsp2010.codeplex.com/documentation)

Comment: This works only for users having outlook. We can't say everyone will use outlook.